# notepad++ regex search replace in html

Tags: notepad++

What I want is to replace:

```
href="products/Integrated-Circuits(ICs)/Linear-Amplifiers-Instrumentation%2cOP-Amps%2cBu.html"
```

to

```
href="#"
```

I hope it isn't to hard for Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \bhref="[^"]+\.html"
Replace: href="#"
```

Comment: [My pattern seems to be working](https://regex101.com/r/xQvjSg/1), at least as tested locally in a demo.

Comment: @Hakançeçen I suspect your cursor is at the end of the file. Tick "Wrap around", then try again.